# Why are some (user)names not clickable?

Tags: support

I just noticed that in this thread: [How can I select to keep data from a chosen site when I clear Private data](https://superuser.com/questions/25052/how-can-i-select-to-keep-data-from-a-chosen-site-when-i-clear-private-data), most of the names aren't clickable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question got migrated from StackOverflow and the user doesn't have a linked account on SuperUser. Therefore, it's a ghost account. They can reclaim the post by associating their account with a SuperUser one.

Comment: This doesn't always work - or the poster is doing it wrong - I've seen a number of questions with a greyed out user name and the same name as a link on an answer. I usually add a comment to the answer for the poster to e-mail the team to get the question re-linked to their new account.

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, there is a second cause of this; if the poster's account has been **deleted** for whatever reason, then they show in that way. There are various reasons to be deleted:

- an account that never did much (perhaps asked one question then vanished) and has been idle for a significant time (months) [may be automatically deleted](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/)
- sometimes accounts are deleted on request by the user
- and sometimes accounts are deleted for inappropriate activity (although in most of these cases we're talking about the pure-spam / pure-troll accounts, and we'd likely delete all their posts as well as their account - so you wouldn't see these posts unless you have 10k)

Comment: +1 I didn't know about the automatic delete.