# Do users with no clickable name gain reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts

Answered [I screwed up, exit in .bashrc](https://serverfault.com/questions/206544/i-screwed-up-exit-in-bashrc/206547)

The user *camel_space* is not clickable - probably because the question was migrated to SF, and that user didn't enable her login on SF.

How works the rep system in this case for her? (I voted up the question, but it did not have ant effect on the user)

Comment: Cannot make camel_space in italics...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are some (user)names not clickable?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15341/why-are-some-usernames-not-clickable)

Comment: Reading this again, it's not a dupe of that question -- this asks about reputation of those users. I mistakenly voted to close and will vote to reopen if it gets closed.

Comment: @Jon: same =( I changed the title to prevent other people from making our mistake..

Comment: @ChrisF Note that you can simply delete your comment...

Comment: @Ring0 - that comment is added by the system when you vote to close. It shows which question is the possible duplicate. It's useful to leave it up so people can easily see which question is being referred to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the answer in the other question, that user does not have an associated account on the migration-target site.

However, voting activity is associated with *posts*. So, if and when the user's unregistered account is associated/merged, all the posts get associated as well. At that point, they will get a rep recalc, which will let the real reputation score show up.

So, the voting activity counts and is valid, but the score will only show up (along with a full user profile) if and when the user's accounts are associated.

Comment: Btw, any reason why the camel_space could not appear in italics in the question? (it does in a comment)

Comment: @ring0: Underscores are control characters for italics, like the asterisk. From playing around a little bit, it seems those controls vary in behaviour between posts and comments.